# promtool error: field groups not found in type config.plain

Tags: prometheus

I'm using the latest version of promtool

```
~/promtool --version
promtool, version 2.37.1 (branch: HEAD, revision: 1ce2197e7f9e95089bfb95cb61762b5a89a8c0da)
  build user:       root@3caaaea7ba87
  build date:       20220912-12:42:39
  go version:       go1.18.6
  platform:         linux/amd64
```

against a simple/example rule file:

```
groups:
- name: example
  rules:
  - alert: HighRequestLatency
    expr: job:request_latency_seconds:mean5m{job="myjob"} > 0.5
    for: 10m
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: High request latency
```

which I took from the [official Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/).

The command I'm using is:

> $ promtool check config

I'm getting this error:

```
Checking rules.yaml
  FAILED: parsing YAML file c.yaml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: field groups not found in type config.plain
```

I don't see what is going wrong here. I tried with other simple rule configs, but to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For alert rules, you should probably try `promtool check rules <filename>`.

Comment: Using check 'rules' (instead of 'config') was the exact change I needed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying the "promtool check config" comand over the file with the rules.

```
/etc/prometheus $ promtool check config prometheus_rules.yml

> Checking prometheus_rules.yml
>  FAILED: parsing YAML file prometheus_rules.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
>  line 1: field groups not found in type config.plain
```

Instead trying the "promtool check config" comand over the prometheus' config file I saw that both files are correct.

```
/etc/prometheus $ promtool check config prometheus.yml

> Checking prometheus.yml
>  SUCCESS: 1 rule files found
> SUCCESS: prometheus.yml is valid prometheus config file syntax

> Checking prometheus_rules.yml
>  SUCCESS: 1 rules found
```

In the documentation I found that for prometheus' configuration file should be used the "**promtool check config**" comand.
For the rules file should be used instead the "**promtool check rules**" comand.

```
/etc/prometheus $ promtool check rules prometheus_rules.yml
> Checking prometheus_rules.yml
>   SUCCESS: 1 rules found
```